# Downloading files one by one with Internet Download Manager

Tags: windows, download-manager

How could I download files one by one (selected files only) in Internet Download Manager 6.11?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new queue and have the queue set to download files sequentially.

[image]

Now whatever files you want to download, drag and drop the files from IDM main window in to that queue.